# Making the program wait for a specific time in C

Tags: c

What I want the code to do is:
printing "Hello",
waiting 2 seconds, and
printing "world".

What happens:
    Once I run the program, it waits two seconds, then prints "helloWorld"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{

time_t current_time = 0; //A variable to save the time

printf("Hello");

current_time = clock();
//wating 2 seconds
for ( ; (clock() - current_time) < (2 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC); );

printf("Wolrd");
return 0;
}
```

As if the wait command is before the two printing commands?!

Comment: Try adding `fflush(stdout);` after `printf("Hello");`

Comment: and use sleep rather than looping http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep

Comment: It works :D Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print a new line to flush stdout :

```
 printf("Hello\n");
```

Currently no characters in the standard output will be displayed because it is line buffered. You can also call the `fflush` function for the same outcome.

Comment: Thank you for the explaining.